# Perform goodness-of-fit test on multiple contingency tables

Tags: goodness-of-fit, contingency-tables

I want to test my theory against a set of scenes. Specifically, I have 10 2x2 contingency table with observation and expected frequencies. Since there is only one model rather than 10 different models, I want an overall p-value covering all data.

My assumption is that my theory can predict the success rate of ALL scenes.

I tried to flatten the tables into a 2x20 contingency table, but the resulting p-value was abnormally high.

Is this theoretically correct? If not, how can I calculate it?

The data structure looks like:

Test scene 1:

|  | Success | Failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Observed | 97 | 53 |
| Expected | 100 | 50 |

Test scene 2:

|  | Success | Failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Observed | 32 | 58 |
| Expected | 30 | 70 |

...

Test scene 10:

|  | Success | Failure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Observed | 101 | 99 |
| Expected | 100 | 100 |

Comment: Maybe you can tell us what the contingency tables represent in the real world, and what the 10 groups is? Maybe different clinical centers? And, what is the research hypothesis?

Comment: Information added.